# Product of two random variables is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

In this thread

[Product of two random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552084/product-of-two-random-variables?rq=1)

one user gave the following explanation of the problem noted in the title:

> There is a slightly more messy but less sneaky approach: Let $X$ and $Y$ be both nonnegative random variables and note that if $X(\omega)Y(\omega)<c$, then there are
>   nonnegative rational numbers $r_1,r_2$ with $X(\omega)\leq r_1$, $Y(\omega)\leq r_2$ and $r_1r_2<c$. Let $R_c$ be the set of all pairs of nonnegative rational numbers with product smaller than $c$ and note that $R_c$ is countable. Then $$(XY)^{-1}\big((-\infty,c)\big)=\bigcup_{(r_1,r_2)\in R_c}X^{-1}\big((-\infty,r_1]\big)\cap Y^{-1}\big((-\infty,r_2]\big).$$

What I don't understand is: Why is he allowed to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are both non-negative?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already know that the sum of two rv is a rv so you can use for a general rv X the identity $X = X^{+} - X^{-}$ where $$X^+ = \max\{X,0\}$$ $$ X^- = \max\{-X,0\}$$

are non-negative rv. So the product of two rv can be traced back to the case of non-negative rv and summation.